# Trying to get an SQL command that gets the new customers from each month but i cant seem to get it working

Tags: sql, sql-server, labview

I am trying to pull the new customers from each month from an SQL database. I've tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT (Name) 
FROM Customer 
WHERE Date_created BETWEEN CONVERT(date, getdate()) AND CONVERT(date, getdate()) - (30)
```

Comment: Can you provide your database schema, and sample data? 
what condition/column tells you it is a new customer? Is there a creation date field? Also show us what query you have so far. Thanks

Comment: Calculate the minimum date a customer showed up in your table = new customers for that month.

Comment: This is the command that i last tried, it may be completely wrong but i am very new to this. SELECT COUNT (Name) FROM Customer WHERE 
Date_created BETWEEN CONVERT(date, getdate()) AND CONVERT(date, getdate()) - (30)

Comment: What kind of database is it? MySQL, SQLServer, Postgre?

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL server management

Comment: How do you define new customer?  How do you define "month".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query I think this would do it simpler :

```
SELECT COUNT (Name) FROM Customer WHERE MONTH(Date_created)= MONTH(GETDATE())
```

although am not sure this is what you expect as your question could be interpreted in several ways

Edit : taking account of different years:

```
SELECT COUNT (Name) FROM Customer 
WHERE MONTH(Date_created)= MONTH(GETDATE())
AND YEAR(Date_created)= YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Could you tell me what this command actually does? Does it get all of the new customers from this month so far or does it get the new customers from today's date - a month?

Comment: @SamGreaves: It counts all customer which were new in the current month, but from every year.

Comment: Right so what could i do for it to just be this current year?

Comment: I edited the answer, add a conditition to match the current year

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the month in `yyyymm` format:

```
SELECT  convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112) as Month
,       count(*)
FROM    Customer
GROUP BY
        convert(varchar(6), getdate(), 112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL:

```
select
   extract(year from Date_created) as yr
  ,extract(month from Date_created) as mth
  ,count(*) 
from Customer
group by
   extract(year from Date_created) as yr
  ,extract(month from Date_created) as mth
order by yr, mth
```

Replace `EXTRACT` with a matching function in you DBMS, e.g. for SQL Server `datepart(year, date)`

Comment: The question is for SQL Server, see OP's comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of using `BETWEEN` with dates (see this blog [What do BETWEEN and the Devil Have in Common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)).  However, the problem with your query is that the dates are in the wrong order.  The smaller value has to go first:

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) 
FROM Customer 
WHERE Date_created BETWEEN CONVERT(date, getdate() - 30) AND CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

This is better written as :

```
SELECT COUNT(Name)
FROM Customer
WHERE Date_Created >= CONVERT(date, getdate() - 30) AND
      Date_Created < CONVERT(date, getdate());
```

I'm not sure if this satisfies your definition of "month", but at least the query will return 30 days worth of creates.